# SelectAll on EditText with Two-Way Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-edittext, selectall, two-way-binding

I have an Activity with a fragment... In this fragment I'm using two-way DataBinging in an EditText. This EditText is binded to a Double property of the object, and because of this, I had to implement an InverseMethod to convert String -> Double and Double -> String...

In my EditText I configured **android:selectAllOnFocus="true"**, and I'm forcing it also on  onCreateView method of the fragment: **edQtd.selectAll()**

The problem is, that when the fragment appears, the EditText has the focus, but the text is not selected, instead, the cursor is before the first number...

I wanted it to show with all the text selected...

Tried to instead of using the inverse method, just concatenate an empty String, but the result was the same...

From what I saw debbuging it, the binding class generated, sets the text after the fragments creation (after I manually called **edQtd.selectAll()**), removing the selection...

Any ideas how to solve it?

**Edit:**
For now I solved it adding a TextChangedListener to the EditText, where I select all the text only the first time the text is changed:

```
edQuantidade.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(selectAllEdQtdText) {
                edQuantidade.selectAll();
                setSelectAllEdQtdText(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try `edQtd.selectAll()` in onResume() of Fragment?

Comment: Tried now, Khemraj, and the it didnt worked out. The code of binding class generated is runned after the OnResume method...

I solved it by adding a TextChangedListener that selects all text only after the 1st change, but I didn'l like this solution...

Comment: You just want to select EditText text after your view opens?

Comment: Yes, I want to select all the text of the EditText right after open the view

Answer (score 0):

Add following attributes on EditText in Layout.

```
<EditText
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    />
```

And remove `edQtd.selectAll()` from code.

**Edit**

Because none solution works. This will work because this will trigger selectAll after a delay. Add this after setting model in binding.

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            edQtd.selectAll();
        }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work, when the setText is executed by the databinding generated class, the selecion is removed...

Comment: From where you get data to set layout?

Comment: I create and bind the object in onCreateView method

Comment: Now it worked, but I strill prefer the other solution I found which you don't have to wait the 500ms to get the text selected... I'll edit my question with this "solution" I found... Anyway, thanks

Comment: Will it not select EditText everytime user change text?

Comment: No, I created a property that starts True, and after the first time the text is chaged I set it to False